# How do i get multiple double inputs separated by ; from one JtextField and store them on an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, double, jtextfield

I have this problem in JAVA where I need to take multiple doubles separated by; from a single jTextField and store them into an array each time I click save button, I also want to set a limit of 5 inputs for example :
12;13;14;15;16 into my jtextfield and then I want it to stop until I click on save and then it became blank and so on
Sorry if I wasn't clear enough it's my first time here and I'm still a beginner in JAVA.
Thanks in advance!
Here is my actual code at the moment, nothing great

```
    package miniprojet;

    public class Notes extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public Notes(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField10 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Enregistrer");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Notes");

        jLabel2.setText("Moyennes");

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);

        jTextField3.setEditable(false);

        jTextField4.setEditable(false);

        jTextField5.setEditable(false);

        jTextField6.setEditable(false);

        jButton2.setText("Trier");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Moyennes Triées");

        jTextField7.setEditable(false);

        jTextField8.setEditable(false);

        jTextField9.setEditable(false);

        jTextField10.setEditable(false);

        jTextField11.setEditable(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 308, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 81, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField11)
                    .addComponent(jTextField10)
                    .addComponent(jTextField9)
                    .addComponent(jTextField8)
                    .addComponent(jTextField7)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                String note =  jTextField1.getText ().replace(";","");

    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double Tab[][];
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Notes dialog = new Notes(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField10;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    public void moyenne() {
        int i,j;
        double moy,s;
        for(i=0;i<60;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
             /*   Tab[i][j]=;*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take the JTextField text with `getText()` method and then you can tokenize this string with `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(textField.getText(),";")`. Then you can store every char between ";" with

```
int i=0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    array[i] = st.nextToken();
    i++;     
}
```

Remember that a size of an array is static and defined when the array is declared and initialized. You can use other data structure, such as an `ArrayList<T>`.

I hope that this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll try this and give you my feedback :)

Comment: It worked thanks a lot,just one more thing if possible,i want my jTextField to only accept something like : 10;11;12;13;14 and nothing more,and each time i click save on Jbutton1 it stores them and the jtextfield become blank and ready to recieve another thing like in the example

Comment: To make a JTextField blank, after the processing you can do `txtField.setText("")`.

Comment: To exclude what is different from 1;2;3;4 you can control the input of txtFiled. For examle you can do 
`String something = txtField.getText();
if(!something.contains(";") txtField.setText("");`

Comment: Or 
`String something = txtField.getText(); 
if(something.isEmpty()) txtField.setText(""); //it means that the txtField is empty;`

Comment: In the end, you can tokenize the string returned by `getText()` method and you can control if it is possible to parse every token (separated by ";") in an integer. If is possible to do that, the input is correct. Otherwise the input is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys helped me a lot ! i'm new and i found your help very useful :)